# How to split SpatialLines in R?

Tags: r, split, spatial

How to split a SpatialLine that consists of two not connected segments?

Following code creates an example:

```
l1 = cbind(c(1,2),c(3,2))
rownames(l1) = letters[1:2]
l2 = cbind(c(3,4),c(1,4))
rownames(l1) = letters[3:4]
Sl1 = Line(l1)
Sl2 = Line(l2)
Ll1 = Lines(list(Sl1), ID="a")
Ll2 = Lines(list(Sl2), ID="b")
Sl = SpatialLines(list(Ll1,Ll2))
m<-gLineMerge(Sl)
```

Actually the reverse function of `gLineMerge()` should do the job.

Comment: You can have the splitted `Lines` object with the command `unlist(m@lines[[1]])`

Comment: Well, what I receive converting the `Lines` into `SpatialLines` is again only on feature.